# I think I believe I feel statements should be introduced properly

Tags: synonyms, writing-style, expression-choice, politeness

In English, a subjective statement or a likewise question is often introduced by either of these phrases:

> - *I reckon [that] …* – *Do you reckon [that] …?* (dialectal)
> - *I think [that] …* – *Do you think [that] …?*
> - *I believe [that] …* – *Do you believe [that] …?*
> - *I feel [that] …* – *Do you feel [that] …?*

The first three have been dealt with in [Are there any differences between "I believe" vs "I think" vs "I reckon"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-there-any-differences-between-i-believe-vs-i-think-vs-i-reckon) already, but *feel* hasn’t been covered as far as I can tell. To me, *I think* is the strongest statement about the validity of what follows, but *I believe* can imply at least as strong an endorsement. When I hear or see *I feel* introducing a testable statement it leaves me with the impression that the individual uttering it neither has the commitment shown by *I believe* nor the expertise required for *I think* and lacks the confidence of either.

Am I right to do so or do most native speakers use *think, believe* and *feel* interchangeably in a truly synonymous fashion? What are the reasons to choose one over the other then, different levels of politeness perhaps or just personal habits?

Comment: I think/believe/feel that you are over-analyzing things.  (All my reckoning abilities died a long time ago.)

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, however as I see it, in order of strength of convictions: I believe, I think, I feel.  You haven't included "it seems to me."

Answer (score 2):

This probably comes under the category of pragmatic linguistics. It is certainly very important in Neuro-linguistic programming (NLP).

People perceive the world via different modalities (vision, sound, feeling etc.).

In NLP it is asserted that a person's speech and writing will betray their dominant modality (modalities). Thus a person who is very visual (perhaps an artist) is likely to use visual terminology, e.g. instead of saying "I understand what you are saying" a visual person might say  "I **see** what you mean", a musician might perhaps say "That **sounds** correct" and a sculptor could say, "I have a **feeling** you are right."

If you subscribe to this view then which a person chooses is personal to them. For that reason there is no objective way to compare such expressions except in the context of the individual who is using them.

> **[Representational systems (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_systems_(NLP))**
>
> Representational systems (also known as sensory modalities and
>   abbreviated to VAKOG or known as the 4-tuple) is a postulated model
>   from neuro-linguistic programming regarding how the human mind
>   supposedly processes and stores information. The central idea of this
>   model is that experience is represented in the mind in sensorial terms
>   ... Bandler and Grinder claim that each person has a "most highly
>   valued" (now commonly termed preferred) representational system in
>   which they are more able to vividly create an experience (in their
>   mind) in terms of that representational system, tend to use that
>   representational system more often than the others, and have more
>   distinctions available in that representation system than the
>   others.[4] So for example a person that most highly values their
>   visual representation system is able to easily and vividly visualise
>   things and has a tendency to do so in preference to creating or
>   recreating an experience in terms of the other representational
>   system.
>   Wkipedia

Answer (score 1):

"I feel" means just that: something or someone has caused me to feel happy, or anxious, or resigned, etc.

"I believe" means that I accept as something as true without proof, be it your word, or religion, or a salesman's unwritten promises, or that I'll become a rock star.

"I think" means I apply rational processes to analyze information, its sources, its applications, its consequences, etc. From this process I might come to form an opinion. With sufficient evidence or proof, I might come to "know."

It makes me a bit nuts when people use these words interchangeablely; it lacks clarity. And if I wanted your feelings about something, I wouldn't have requested your thoughts.

"I reckon" means I calculate something. Perhaps I calculate a navigational course by means of dead reckoning, or reckon accounts. And in several regional dialects it is used synonymously with I think, I calculate, or I figure.

Comment: This would be an acceptable explanation in an ESL classroom, but is hardly convincing on EL&U. Whatever people believe about the 'proper' use of words has little to do with their actual use. Please support your claims with authoritative references, examples of usage, etc.

Comment: *Feel* in the sense that is relevant here doesn't stand for happiness, anxiety, etc.; one can believe something with or without proof; thinking is not always rational.